# How do I solve Running "flutter packages get"

Tags: dart, flutter

Few Days ago, everything was running fine but suddenly I'm facing Flutter Packages Get Problem. Long time I've to wait after create the project. Please take a look and give me a solution **:(** **Screenshot below**

[image]

Comment: you dont have connection to the internet

Comment: Internet connect totally fine @pskink

Comment: can you ping pub.dartlang.org?

Comment: I think NO. Here I received Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Comment: But I can Ping other sites but why I can't ping pub. Please help me out.

Comment: it's your network, not mine, how can I know what you did with it?

Comment: You might have installed Flutter in a directory where your current user account does not have write access, or you are behind a proxy and didn't configure it for Dart/Pub/Flutter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But 2 days ago, its working now. What happened now then how do i fix it @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Might be an intermittent network issue on your side or pub.dartlang.org or somewhere in between.

Comment: Totally confused. Even I can't visit pub.dartlang.org till I changed my IP. What's going on :( If I change my IP i can access dart site not before :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be facing the DNS problem. Could you please update your DNS setting like this and let me know if it works. Here is the solution =>

Find Your Internet Options > Go To Properties Of the ISP or Connected Device > Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and Click Properties > 
Use the following DNS server addresses >

```
Preferred DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
Alternate DNS Server: 8.8.4.4
```

Give it try. After you set this if you can visit pub.dartlang.or then you will get packages too. Thank you.

Comment: Sure Sir, I'll try :)

Comment: How is it possible. It's working super cool. Thank you so so much Sir. I appreciate your help. Thank you again and again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in China or your IP address has been changed, try https://flutter.dev/community/china